Group algebra of infinite dihedral group
Consider the infinite dihedral group $\mathbf{D}_\infty=\left\langle s,t\mid s^{2}=t^{2}=1\right\rangle $. I want to show that the corresponding group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{D}_\infty]$ is finitely generated over its center $\mathcal{Z}$, meaning that it is a finitely generated $\mathcal{Z}$-module.
I started by characterizing the center of $\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{D}_\infty]$ and proved that it consists of all linear combinations of elements of the form $(st)^n+(st)^{-n} \in \mathbb{C}[\mathbf{D}_\infty]$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. However, I struggle to show that there exist finitely many elements $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{C}[\mathbf{D}_\infty]$ such that every element can be written as a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n z_ix_i$, where $z_1,...,z_n\in\mathcal{Z}$. Does anyone have a hint?

An algebra that is finitely generated as a module is usually called finite algebra. For algebras, the term finitely generated normally refers to algebra generators.
